# Why is the size of used space of a share different from the used space of a network drive targeting to that share?

Tags: windows, network-share, dfs

We have a share that shows 350GB (376.544.187.272 Bytes) as used.
If I mount that Share as a network drive it shows me 304 GB (326.777.810.944 Bytes) as used.

The underlying NetApp Volume shows me 304 GB used space.

Why is there a different between a share and the share mounted as network drive.

Thx 4 any answer,

tbol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mh... after hours of investigation nad posting here I found out that deduplication is the point of difference.

Rightclick -> properties shows the real used space/size of files
while a mapped network drive shows the size with deduplication.